# finding out HTML equivalents of latex math symbols

Tags: symbols, html

Unlike the other unresolved questions about painless latex to HTML conversion,
I just want to know the conversions for math symbols.

For example, when I give

```
\Leftrightarrow
```

as input to that program, I should get back

```
&hArr;
```

Alternatively, is there an equivalent of :
detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

for HTML symbols?

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11534/86

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In HTML, references like `&hArr;` are nothing but notations indicating specific characters, and as soon as you know the identity of a symbol as a character, by its Unicode number or Unicode name, you can check the [HTML 4 list of named references](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/sgml/entities.html) or the much larger [HTML5 CR list of named references](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#named-character-references) (the added references have much more limited browser support, and using them is almost always a bad idea). On the other hand, you don’t achieve anything except perhaps some source code readability by using the named references instead of numeric references like `&#x21d4;`. The numeric references are more reliable, since there have been some silent changes in the meanings of named references, between HTML versions. – Besides, when generating HTML, you can use the character themselves, if you are generating a UTF-8 encoded file, as you should.

Thus, the key question would be how to find the identity of a character. This needs to be resolved case by case, since LaTeX is about producing graphic presentations of symbols, not characters as defined in character code standards. For example, [The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) does not identify characters by code number or Unicode name, it just shows glyphs produced. In many cases, there is no real ambiguity, but often there is.

The [Shapecatcher](http://shapecatcher.com/) page lets you draw a symbol and then it tries to recognize it as a Unicode character. But recognizing a character from a graphic is complicated and risky. When I tested by drawing a symbol that looks like the one `\Leftrightarrow` produces, I got several suggestions, including U+27FA LONG LEFT RIGHT DOUBLE ARROW, but not U+21D4 LEFT RIGHT DOUBLE ARROW. These are encoded as separate characters in Unicode, and they can apparently be regarded as corresponding to `\Leftrightarrow` and `\Longleftrightarrow`, but distinguishing the two can be difficult or impossible when considering just one graphic, one glyph (since the length of the arrow naturally depends on font design, too).

Comment: thanks for the pointer to shapecatcher -- i hadn't heard of it, and intend to spread the word via my tugboat column.  regarding "long" vs. "ordinary" arrows -- the "long" versions in unicode are intended to indicate arrows that can be stretched, a condition that requires markup; the short ones are intended to always remain the same size.  i'll check on the text in the [unicode technical report on support for math](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr25/) to make sure this is clear.